# How do I remove a device that I no longer own from Find My?

Tags: find-my

I sold my MacBook Pro a while ago and even if I did signed out from my Apple account, I realize now that it still appears in Find My and I see the location of the new owner.

When I select that device in my Find My, I have the option to erase it or mark as lost. I do not see any option to remove it from my account though.

If I right click on the device in the list as some suggest, I also do not see the `Remove` option

[image]

The [Apple support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/findmy-mac/fmm2832fb8f0/mac) page was not helpful.

How can I remove it?

**UPDATE**

I noticed that when the device is offline, I do have the option to remove it. If I do so, I confirm with my Apple password and the device is removed but appears again after some seconds in the device lists.

[image]

Comment: Reading the Apple Support, I'm afraid your situation is similar/the same to "*Turn off Activation Lock on a device you no longer have*", especially "*If you sold or gave away your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, Mac or Apple Watch **and you forgot to turn off Find My [device]**, you can still remove Activation Lock using the Find My app.*" (emphasis mine), in which you have to erase the device.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on the device in the sidebar and choose ‘Remove This Device’.

[image]

As explained in the linked Apple Support article, there should also be an option to remove the device underneath the Erase button when viewing the device on the map. You may need to scroll down to see it.

[image]

Comment: I had never seen it done this way. If I sign in to appleid.apple.com and click on "Devices" on the left side of the page all your devices are there, click on the one you want to remove and there will be a button to remove the device. I presume this works similarly in other countries with the country specific website...

Comment: @SteveChambers That is a different list. Find My is strictly activation lock & tracking. The device list on appleid.apple.com is more related to device authorization and sign in

Comment: @grg well that's the issue. I do not see the `Remove Device` option. Even if I right click on the device, I can only Erase it but not remove it. On the screenshot I posted you can see that I cannot scroll any further. The option is just not there